# What the difference between SerialPort control and SerialPort class in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am using c# serialPort to communication with inverter that is used in solar power station.

Now I have a issue: when I use SerialPort control dragged from toolbox, the DataReceived event will no be fired, but when trun to use SerialPort class, it is working.

Can anybody please kindly tell me something about it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am afraid why that's not working. Indeed both are same. There is no different at all.

[SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) inherits from `Component` so it can appear in `ToolBox`.

When you drag from toolbox or create instance using `new keyword` you're obviously doing same thing.

To investigate why that's not working I'll suggest you to find the difference between the properties you set in code as well as `*designer.cs`.

Comment: Hi Sriram, many thanks for your reply. follow your instruction, I removed "this.serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.serialPort1_DataReceived);" in Designer.cs, then generate this event again, and it can be fired. Thank you.

Comment: If this answer helped you mark as answer, so that others will be benefited